# Функция input_month() возвращает только первое введенное значение. В чем ошибка?

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите решить проблему.
Почему-то в переменную month возвращаетcя только первое значение, присвоенное переменной enter_month внутри функции input_month().

```
def input_month():
    enter_month = str.lower(input('Введите название месяца: '))
    check_month = False
    for i in range(len(list_of_months)):
        if list_of_months[i][0] == enter_month:
            check_month = True
    if check_month == False:
        enter_month = input_month()
    else:
        print('OK\n')
        print(enter_month) # Здесь выводится верное текущее значение
        return enter_month


list_of_months = [['январь', 31], ['февраль', 29], ['март', 31], ['апрель', 30], ['май', 31], ['июнь', 30], ['июль', 31], ['август', 31], ['сентябрь', 30], ['октябрь', 31], ['ноябрь', 30], ['декабрь', 31]]

month = input_month() # Почему сюда возвращается None???
```

Comment: А что должно быть? Что вводите? Что ожидается?

Comment: Вводится название месяца, и выполняется проверка корректности ввода согласно заданному списку. Независимо от того, сколько раз введено несуществующее название, и, соответственно, сколько раз перезапущена функция input_month(), возвращается из нее только первое введенное значение строки, а должно возвращаться первое корректно введенное.

Comment: Потому что у вас рекурсия. Выполните программу пошагово и увидите

Comment: Переместите return в блок else

Comment: Из блока else возвращает None

Comment: А покажите ваши входные данные и что вы получаете на выходе

Comment: Переписал код, избавился от функции проверки, включил проверку вводимых данных в функцию ввода, return положил в блок else, результат тот же: из блока else возвращается None. Из тела функции все также возвращается первое присвоенное переменной enter_month значение (верное или неверное)

Comment: @edge1312 еще раз. Добавьте входные данные и выходные

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev Вводится с клавиатуры название месяца, и выполняется проверка корректности ввода согласно заданному списку. На выходе переменной month должно быть присвоено значение, соответствующее любому [i][0] -му элементу списка, т.е корректное название месяца

Comment: print(enter_month) в блоке else выдает верное текущее значение переменной, а в month возвращается None

Comment: @edge1312 вы вообще мой вопрос видите?) Я спрашиваю, что вы вводите с клавиатуры и что вы получаете, что считаете, что у вас не верно выполняется программа

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev Вводить можно любую ересь до тех пор, пока не введется строка, соответствующая одному из элементов списка. Эта строка и должна быть возвращена. https://repl.it/@egde1312/test?lite=&classroom_template=&outputonly=&fileName=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прилагаю рабочий вариант вашей функции

```
def input_month():
    enter_month = str.lower(input('Введите название месяца: '))
    check_month = False
    for i in range(len(list_of_months)):
        if list_of_months[i][0] == enter_month:
            check_month = True
    if check_month == False:
        return input_month()
    else:
        return enter_month
```

Вместе с тем хочу заметить, что использование рекурсии для ввода это несколько не рационально. Кроме того напрашивается не список списков, а словарь для хранения месяцев. Использование словаря не только упростит поиск месяца, но и позволит легко получить число дней в заданном месяце.

```
dict_of_months = {'январь':31, 'февраль':29, 'март':31,'апрель':30, 'май':31, 'июнь':30,
                  'июль':31, 'август':31, 'сентябрь':30, 'октябрь':31, 'ноябрь':30, 'декабрь': 31}

def input_month(months):
    enter_month=""
    while enter_month not in months.keys():
        enter_month = str.lower(input('Введите название месяца: '))
    return enter_month
```

Ввод и вывод

```
month=input_month2(dict_of_months)
print(month)
print(dict_of_months[month])
```

Answer (score 0):

А кто будет передавать локальную переменную(локальную в функции) вовне? В каждом вызове создается своя локальная enter_month. замени.

```
if check_month == False:

    enter_month = input_month()
```

и верни ретурн на место, а то ноня придэ

```
def input_month():
    enter_month = str.lower(input('Введите название месяца: '))
    check_month = False
    for i in range(len(list_of_months)):
        if list_of_months[i][0] == enter_month:
            check_month = True
    if check_month == False:
        enter_month = input_month()
    else:
        print('OK')
        print('')  
    return enter_month


list_of_months = [['январь', 31], ['февраль', 29], ['март', 31], ['апрель', 30], ['май', 31], ['июнь', 30], ['июль', 31], ['август', 31], ['сентябрь',  ['октябрь', 31], ['ноябрь', 30], ['декабрь', 31]]

month = input_month()
```

У меня все работает

Comment: Заменил. Результат тот же

Comment: СУПЕР!!! СПАСИБО!!! ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!